# How can I access a Django model's reverse foreign key from a staticmethod?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

Suppose I have 3 Django models:

```
class MyModelA(models.Model):
    my_int = models.IntegerField()

    @staticmethod
    def my_Astatic_method():
        return "AHello"

class MyModelB(models.Model):
    my_int = models.IntegerField()
    my_a = models.ForeignKey(MyModelA, related_name="MyModelB_a")


    @staticmethod
    def my_Bstatic_method():
        return "BHello"

class MyModelC(models.Model):
    my_int = models.IntegerField()
    my_b = models.ForeignKey(MyModelB, related_name="MyModelC_b")

    @staticmethod
    def my_Cstatic_method():
        return "CHello"
```

I have an instance of `MyModelA` called `a`. From within a method of `a`, I would like to call `my_Cstatic_method()`. How can I do it?

`a.MyModelB_a.model.my_Bstatic_method()` works to call `MyModelB`'s static method. But I don't know how to get one level down into `MyModelC`'s static methods from `MyModelB`'s `model` attribute. How should I do it?

Surprisingly, there is no `model` attribute for the object `a.MyModelB_a.model.MyModelC_b`

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to bother with the foreign keys. You've got a static method, you can just call it via the class: `MyModelC.my_Cstatic_method()`.

Answer (score 0):

After accessing model B from model A, you don't have model instance anymore, but model class.

With class, there is no fields but rather field descriptors, also for related fields, so there shoudl be `MyModelC_b` here:

```
a.MyModelB_a.model.MyModelC_b
```

but, as I said this isn't a field, but it have reference to related model as an sub-attribute in attribute `related`:

```
a.MyModelB_a.model.MyModelC_b.related.model
```

using that, you can now accss your static function from model C

```
a.MyModelB_a.model.MyModelC_b.related.model.my_Cstatic_method()
```

Comment: Sorry Gwyn, I was confused in writing the OP. I have since corrected it. I have an instance of `MyModelA` and am trying to call a static method of `MyModelC`.

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't work: https://gist.github.com/saqib-zmi/cbda21d461246df2d225. The `related` attribute sends me back to `MyModelB` instead of to `MyModelC`.